# Excel not recognizing cell values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting

In the process of pulling data from an audit, the platform returns most of the data as a "true/false" format. Specifically it's all lowercase, and aligned to the left with no spaces before or after and no obvious formatting outside of that. However, when trying to use formulas that identify or count based on the value of the cell, such as COUNTIF, excel will not recognize the value of the cell. Used ISTEXT to see if it's a value or formatting issue and it will return a TRUE result. Used ISLOGICAL to check if it recognized the "true/false" value and got a false result. However, if i click into the cell string (as if to edit the text) and then press enter, the cell will reformat, capitalizing all font, centering the cell, and changing the values of the cell checks. ISTEXT becomes false, ISLOGICAL becomes true, and the cell is able to be interacted with by if and count functions. Any ideas why this is? And any solutions to address this? i'd rather not go through 200+ cells manually fixing it.

Comment: If imported data treated as text to excel then use `COUNTIF(A:A,"true"` means criteria as text. If they are logical true/false data then use `Countif(A:A, TRUE)`. When you edit data on excel and finish it by enter or click to other cell then excel automatically reformat cell based on data entered to it. This is by default behavior of excel. It you want to convert all to logical true/false then use `=--A1` to convert text to logical value.

Comment: Text formatting strikes again... I've rarely seen it do anything other than mess up worksheets! Don't treat it as data then, treat it as text that needs processing to become usable data.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to try:

1. Use F9 or Control+Alt+Shift+F9 to refresh the workbook.
2. Highlight the entire dataset and try to set the cell formatting from text to general
3. Highlight Data -> Data Tab -> Text To Columns -> Finish